# C# Google Storage Client - Upload file - Fail if already exists

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I am using the google storage c# client. I am uploading a file to a specific location.

Sample code:

```
private void UploadFile(string bucketName, string localPath,
    string objectName = null)
{
    var storage = StorageClient.Create();
    using (var f = File.OpenRead(localPath))
    {
        objectName = objectName ?? Path.GetFileName(localPath);
        storage.UploadObject(bucketName, objectName, null, f);
        Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {objectName}.");
    }
}
```

When uploading a file to the same location more than once, the new version overwrites the old version.

I want the upload to fail and throw exception(because the file already exists). How can I do that?

> **Note:**  The obvious solution is to check if the file exists before uploading, but this does not cover me from race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the overwrite using `ifGenerationMatch(0)`:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#parameters

I am not a C# expert, but I think in C# this is available via the `UploadObjectOptions`:

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UploadObjectOptions.html

Specifically:

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UploadObjectOptions.html#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_UploadObjectOptions_IfGenerationMatch

Comment: This works well. Setting uploadOptions.IfGenerationMatch = 0; When uploading you need to catch (GoogleApiException e) when (e.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed) to handle the case where the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage automatically overwrite an existing object in a bucket as it is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#uploads)

> "If you upload a file with the same name as an existing object in your
> Cloud Storage bucket, the existing object is overwritten. To keep
> older versions of the object, enable Object Versioning."

As an alternative, I think you can check if the object exist getting the metadata. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414817/google-cloud-storage-check-if-object-exists-app-engine-java) other Stackoverflow question can help you as reference and [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-view-object-metadata-csharp) other GCP documentation shows you how to implement it using C#.

```
private void GetMetadata(string bucketName, string objectName)
{
    var storage = StorageClient.Create();
    var storageObject = storage.GetObject(bucketName, objectName);
    
}
```